# excel vba generate format cells with different font color

Tags: excel, vba, fonts, colors

I want to generate an excel sheet in a certain layout with vba. One of my subroutines is for font color. It looks like this:

```
Sub SetFont(cell1, cell2 As range, fcolor As String)

range(cell1, cell2).Select
If fcolor = "w" Then
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
ElseIf fcolor = "b" Then
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

But it does not work. The font is always generated in black. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me, however there is a reversal; `xlThemeColorLight1` produces dark text and 
`xlThemeColorDark1` creates lighter text, which is pretty dumb but there you go.

```
Sub foo()
SetFont Range("A1"), Range("A6"), "b"
End Sub

Sub SetFont(cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, fcolor As String)
If fcolor = "w" Then
    With Range(cell1, cell2).Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    End With
ElseIf fcolor = "b" Then
    With Range(cell1, cell2).Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Unrelated, but if you have `cell1, cell2 As range` only `cell2` is declared of type `range`, `cell1` remains a variant.

Comment: +1 for the cell1 type declaration note, good example of a common issue

Answer (score 0):

May be try this :
    Sub SetFont(cell1, cell2 As range, fcolor As String)
    range(cell1, cell2).Select
    If fcolor = "w" Then
    With Selection.Interior
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    ElseIf fcolor = "b" Then
    With Selection.Interior
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    End If

End Sub